can't push to Github because the file that exceeded the maximum size has been deleted
I have had multiple attempt to push my commits to my repository but the file it says is too large does not appear in my repository.
allen@ubuntu:~/Projects/Mapper/mapper_QT$ git push
Enumerating objects: 290, done.
Counting objects: 100% (239/239), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (178/178), done.
Writing objects: 100% (182/182), 105.54 MiB | 1.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 182 (delta 125), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (125/125), completed with 51 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 0730b46f05dd95225e52b3f579b71ad134147f2b6710c5e580ba973961876a9f
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper is 117.74 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper is 117.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/allenck/mapper.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/allenck/mapper.git'
allen@ubuntu:~/Projects/Mapper/mapper_QT$ git rm --cached build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper
allen@ubuntu:~/Projects/Mapper/mapper_QT$ ls -l build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper
-rwxrwxr-x 1 allen allen 123726384 Oct 29 20:37 build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper
allen@ubuntu:~/Projects/Mapper/mapper_QT$ ls -l File build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper

The file in question is an executable file My  which never should have been in the repository and which I deleted. My repository is :
https://github.com/allenck/mapper

When you delete a file, git generates new commit to delete that, and git saves history of that file deleted.
So you can't push it to remote repository.
To remove that file from history, you should run git rm --cached file
If it also doesn't work, you can consider to clear git history and generate new commits, but it can lead to losing commit history.
Good approach is to reset commit until large file is commited, and then re-generate from that.

I have tried to do that but it saysit can't find the file,allen@ubuntu:~/Projects/Mapper/mapper_QT/mapper_app$ git rm --cached build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper
fatal: pathspec 'build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper' did not match any files

your path build/Desktop_Qt_6_8_0-Debug/mapper_app/mapper doesn't match, it says. You can specify as filename. important: you can check git graph to see deleted file is remained in history. If git graph history contains that file, you can't push it.

Clearing the history seems to have solved the problem.

Yeah, if you can accept losing commit history, it's good choice.
